# Can't install Windows 7 (boot)

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, usb-flash-drive

First of all, I can't boot my Windows 7. I get a black screen with a cursor up in the left corner.

So, I tried using Windows 7 installation which I've put on my flash drive.
To boot from the drive, I've changed the boot order to boot from the drive first.
It boots but does not find any HDD to install Windows on (which is pretty logical, I don't boot the HDD soon enough for the installer).

But if I put the HDD in front of the flash drive in the boot order, it will just try to load Windows 7 and I will get the black screen again.
I've tried putting the HDD first and clicking <kbd>F8</kbd> a lot. All I've got is an error. Something about some software change. I don't know.

Help me please, I can't do anything with my laptop until then.

Comment: Pressing F8 should allow you to have the boot options menu (Safe Mode, Safe Mode with Networking, etc.). Is that the screen you are getting when you press F8, or is it different? If you could write down the error message you're getting, that would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried booting from a CD/DVD by chance?

Answer (score 4):

I get this behaviour (black screen, flashing cursor) if I have certain brands of USB flash drives plugged in during boot, regardless of the boot order. When I remove all flash drives and reboot, Windows starts normally.

Comment: This happened to me, oddly Windows would boot from my newly installed SSD with Win8 on, but when trying the HDD, just a flashing cursor

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to boot with USB flash attached could also be a problem with motherboard BIOS.Especially on older motherboards.For example my ASUS A8N32 SLI-Deluxe recieved an updated BIOS that fixes a problem of this nature.

And if you are still not able to boot then i would be better to disconnect all unnessesary drives/devices during install and optionally load driver for SATA/IDE controller.

Also make sure Win7 is original.I dont really trust 3rd party manufacturer disks or ones downloaded from torrent and dubious sources.